# How to find formula for a Bijection

Tags: functions

Need help figuring this one out, came up in class and I have no idea how to write a proof for this

Let E denote the even integers. Find a bijection f : Z → E. Your answer should
include a definition of the function, a proof that it is one-to-one, and a proof that it is
onto.

Answer (score 2):

every integer x has a counterpart in E, 2x.  So the function is the one where 'n' is mapped to '2n'...

It is fairly trivial to show that it is 1-1 and onto

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:\Bbb{Z}\to{\Bbb{E}}:f(n)=2n$.

Injective: suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $2x=2y$, so $x=y$.

Surjective: let $E\in\Bbb{E}$. Then $E=2m$ for some integer $m$. Then $f(m)=E$.